# How to get hidden field value in a html button in code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have created an HTML table with a repeater. In this table, I added a button column. It is an HTML button because ASP buttons not working inside of the  tag. Therefore, I added an ASP hidden field inside of this HTML button to get selected row ID. I tried several ways to get the ID from the hidden field. I want to get selected row ID when the button click.

**I have tried followings**

I have tried this code but shows error in **SendValueToSender(id);** line. SendValueToSender is shown in red line using suggestions It generated method. But when I run the code and click the button shows error.

**button_edit_ServerClick**

```
    protected void button_edit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var btn = (HtmlButton)sender;
            var child = btn.FindControl("hidden");
            string id = Convert.ToString(((HiddenField)child).Value);
            SendValueToSender(id);
            Response.Write("id" + id);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Response.Write(exception);
        }
    }
```

**Generated method for SendValueToSender**

```
     private void SendValueToSender(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**Error-After add SendValueToSender method**

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at EasyTravel.Manage.ManageNode.SendValueToSender(String id) in C:\Users\kularathna\source\repos\EasyTravel\EasyTravel\Manage\ManageNode.aspx.cs:line 241 at EasyTravel.Manage.ManageNode.button_edit_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\kularathna\source\repos\EasyTravel\EasyTravel\Manage\ManageNode.aspx.cs:line 229

```
229 - SendValueToSender(id);
241 - throw new NotImplementedException();
```

**PageLoad Method**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Create Database Connection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= LAPTOP-J70EHC58 ; Initial Catalog= Bus_Management_System ; Integrated Security = True ; Connect Timeout = 30 ; ");
        con.Open();

        //Retrieve node details
        string sqlst = "SELECT * FROM Node ";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlst, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlData.Fill(dt);
        rptrNode.DataSource = dt;
        rptrNode.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

**ManageNode.aspx**

```
    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Node_ID</th>
                                        <th>Node_Name</th>
                                        <th>Starting_Node</th>
                                        <th>Ending_Node</th>
                                        <th>Distance_Between_Nodes</th>
                                        <th>Ticket_Price</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrNode" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNodeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Node_ID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNodeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Node_Name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartingNode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Starting_Node") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEndingNode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ending_Node") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDistance" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Distance_Between_Nodes") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTicketPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ticket_Price") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="btn btn-success" id="button_edit" onserverclick="button_edit_ServerClick">
                                                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" Value='<%#Eval("Node_ID") %>' />
                                                        Edit
                                                    </button>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </tbody>


                            </table>
```

**Button Column**(It is in above ManageNode.aspx)

```
    <td>
      <button runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="btn btn-success" id="button_edit" onserverclick="button_edit_ServerClick">
          <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" Value='<%#Eval("Node_ID") %>' />
      Edit
     </button>
          </td>
```

Comment: Why don't try ajax calls rather than this. On Button Click `return func(Id);`

Comment: I didn't use ajax before. I want to get ID in serverside. using that id I want to make reservation corrosponding id

Comment: okay. I will post the answer, that method have that `Id` as parameter that u r looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Design part, Load Jquery Js and Page Js.

```
<td>
  <button runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="btn btn-success" 
  id="button_edit" onclick="func('<%#Eval("Node_ID") %>')">
  Edit
 </button>
</td>
```

In Page Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //button Click Function.
 function func(Id){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../ManageNode.aspx/SendValueToSender",

        data: "{ID: '" + Id + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var tdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Data not found.');
        }

    });
 }
});
```

In Server side.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendValueToSender(string ID)
{
   //do your stuff. 
}
```

Comment: In this SendValueToSender(string ID) method what I suppose to do? I can't understand it.

Comment: [WebMethod]
public static void SendValueToSender(string ID)
{
   //What I suppose to do in here???
}